# Fragment Acitivty recreates fragments after the app is paused

Tags: java, android

When I pause the app for a few moments the activity's Fragmnetos are recreated

```
public class CopycatActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CopycatInterface {

    public void flipFragment(int type) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();

    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, zWaitFragment);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, zMasterMode);
            break;
        case 3:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, zCopyMode);
            break;
        case 4:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, zRateDraws);
            break;
        case 5:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, zWinnerFragment);
            break;
        case 6:
            ft.replace(R.id.container, zSleepMode);
            break;
    }
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
  }
}
```

Depending on which fragment I am in, when paused it is reset

Comment: and where you call `flipFragment` method?

Comment: I call it on interfaces, like buttoes or when a timer runs out